# How to calculate ratio of a column based on values of a subset of this data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame :

```
date           value     country
2016-10-1      1         US
2016-10-1      3         FR
2016-10-1      4         Other
2016-10-2      3         US
2016-10-2      2         FR
```

Here is the reproductible example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
    date=c("2016-10-01","2016-10-01","2016-10-01","2016-10-02","2016-10-02"),
    value=c(1,3,4,3,2),
    country=c("US", "FR", "Other", "US", "FR"))
```

I would like to add a new column "ratio" which calculates ratio of a row compared to all rows of the same date.

For example, for the date 2016-10-1 we have a total value of 8. So the ratio of the row 2016-10-1 / US is `1/8` and the ratio of 2016-10-1 / FR is `3/8`.

The expected data frame is :

```
date           value     country   ratio
2016-10-1      1         US        0.125
2016-10-1      3         FR        0.375
2016-10-1      4         Other     0.5
2016-10-2      3         US        0.6
2016-10-2      2         FR        0.4
```

I have tried something like that :

```
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(ratio = value / sum(mydf[date==date]))
```

But, this is not a surprise, it doesn't run. I don't know how to calculate the total of a given date.

Any clue?

Comment: Try `group_by(mydf, date) %>% mutate(ratio = value / sum(value))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is

```
df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(ratio = value/sum(value))
```

Comment: damn, it's so simple that I have missed it. Thanks ;)

Comment: use `mean` instead of this `value/sum(value)`

Comment: Why using mean? This is not the mean but a ratio, isn't it?

Comment: What would you do if you wanted the calculated value to be the ratio between other countries' value and the US? So for US the new value would be 1 and for other countries it would be their value in that year divided by the US's value in that year. It seems a very similar problem.